# How to validate datepicker date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a `textbox` with a JQuery `datepicker` in my MVC application. If I manually enter the date I need to validate for valid date and max date at the same time.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are few workarounds for this:
You may disable manual inputs alltogether by using

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly" />
```

This will prevent users from entering invalid dates. Afterwards, set the jquery code where the datepicker is called to:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
           //other criteria
            maxDate: maxdate
        });
```

Or else if you really want manual date entering enabled, try this jquery code which uses the `Globalize` library to minimize errors caused by syntax; if the date cannot be recognized, an empty string will be returned:

```
$('#myDateTextBox').blur(function () {
    var parsedDate = Globalize.parseDate($(this).val());
    if (parsedDate == null) {
       //


     } 
        else {
           var maxDate = new Date();
           maxdate = '2015-09-05';

          if (parsedDate < maxDate){
           // Do your code
           }
          else{
                 //
               }
        }
```